# MS SQL Server Создание ролей и аутентификация

Tags: sql, sql-server, аутентификация

Не могу разобраться с аутентификацией в MS SQL Server. Стоит такая задача:

Клиент в sql запросе дает серверу лог и пасс, и авторизируется в сервере. Не могу сделать авторизацию. Роли создал, Юзеров сделал, логины тоже, но при попытке SQL аутентификации (даже если в SQL Management Studio) - выдает ошибку

> Ошибка входа ...

Да, понимаю, что то сделал не правильно с ролями\юзерами\логинами

Помогите хорошим гайдом или расскажите как создать роли, юзеров и логины SQL запросом

Такой код я использовал:

```
    USE db_Browsing_history
    EXEC sp_addrole 'STUDENT'
    GRANT INSERT ON Student TO STUDENT
    GRANT EXECUTE TO STUDENT
    EXEC sp_addlogin 'testStudent','123', 'db_Browsing_history'
    EXEC sp_adduser 'testStudent','testStudent'
    EXEC sp_addrolemember 'STUDENT', 'testStudent'
```

При авторизации ввожу `testStudent` и `123`. Выдает

> Ошибка входа пользователя 'testStudent'

Comment: Какой режим аутентификации у SQL Server? Windows или Mixed? И хорошо бы указывать версии продуктов в вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался с проблемой - код я написал правильно, нужно было в настройках разрешить Sql авторизацию. Тк по дефолту - она отключена была

**UPD**

в *MS SQL Server 2008 R2* по умолчанию отключен режим авторизации *Mixed mode* что бы включить его принудительно необходимо сделать следующее:

1. Открыть *Редактор реестра*: Пуск=>Выполнить=>"Regedit";
2. Открыть следующий ключ реестра: *HKLM/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS/MSSQLServer/LoginMode*
3. Установить значение ключа в **2**.

после перезапуска *SQL Server* настройки вступят в силу
более подробно [тут](http://samolisov.blogspot.ru/2010/07/mixed-mode-ms-sql-server-2008-r2.html)

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так.
После создания логина и юзера должна работать авторизация. Попробуйте залогиниться через студию.

```
USE db_Browsing_history
GO

-- Пароль подлиннее
CREATE LOGIN [testStudent] WITH PASSWORD=N'123456_qwerty',  DEFAULT_DATABASE=[db_Browsing_history],
DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

CREATE USER [testStudent] FOR LOGIN [testStudent]
GO

CREATE ROLE [STUDENT] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
GO

EXEC sp_addrolemember N'STUDENT', N'testStudent'
GO
```

Далее раздать необходимые гранты.